# Socket.io wss needed

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am coding Chat System for my website and I have code ready and everything is fine, BUT there is one issue: I need to have wss for socket.io not ws. Idk how to make this so I didnt tried nothing. Maybe some1 knows how to do that? I am using CloudFlare for https

Comment: Does anyone can help me?